# Sounds are canceling eachother out?

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, service, timer

I have some code where there is audio on button click **and** audio in ten second intervals (in a background service). I have the following code to stop the button audio when the ten second interval plays, and it works fine:

```
public static void myPop(Context context){
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(!manager.isMusicActive()) {       //Only if there isn't any other audio playing
        MediaPlayer pop = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pop);
        pop.start();
    }
    else{
        Log.v(TAG, "Audio is already playing");
    }
}
```

This works fine, and it stops one audio from playing (pop) to let the other audio play(The one from the background service). Now, I am getting the issue when they both play at the same time. For example, when I tap the button at the **exact** same time as when the audio from the background service is about to start. When that happens, my app automatically mutes itself! Is there any way to give a preference to the background service audio? Somehow say that: **If two audio pieces start at the exact same time, I want to let the background service audio to play.** I have been searching for this all day now, but it seems to not be a common problem...? I really appreciate your help in solving this issue!

Thanks,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

I think when you click the button the `media` has not updated its status. So it will call the pop. To prevent this, wait for sometime before checking the status.

```
 public static void myPop(Context context){

 try{
    Thread.sleep(500);//500ms = 0.5s
 }catch(InterruptedException ex){
 }
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    //Wait for sometime and then check status 

    if(!manager.isMusicActive() && hasDelayed1s) {       //Only if there isn't any other audio playing
        MediaPlayer pop = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pop);
        pop.start();

    }
    else{
        Log.v(TAG, "Audio is already playing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wont this only stop the audio from playing over itself? That's not the problem though, I want to stop the two separate audios from canceling each other out. Please explain. Thanks so much for your response!

Comment: But that's not the problem. myPop is going fine. The problem is, if pop starts at the **same** time as my **other** MediaPlayer (which is running in the background), then **both** the sounds are muting. Each individual sound is fine, it's just when both of them play at the same time, they cancel out. How can I fix this? Correct me if I misunderstood you. Thanks so much!

Comment: What could the issue be?

Comment: Can you see the updated answer. If you want i can post some code for delay checking

Comment: How long should I wait. Can you post the delay checking stuff, as I am not too familiar with it. Thanks!

Comment: I will mark you best answer once I get this! Thanks

Comment: There are couple of methods for delay Have you tried the updated answer! I think 0.5 sec will be OK. . Hope this help.

Comment: The problem with this is that the delay will be too much. I still wanted the sound to appear as if it was coming right after the button was pressed

Comment: Yes! But does that solve the problem? I think you can select a shorter time and remember that emulator work much slower compared to real device: 0.2sec is generally acceptable.

Comment: Alright, I will try it. The thing is, this issue only happens very  rarely, but when it does, it is an issue. I will get back to you soon. Thanks!